# Google sheets - Get active cell row in cell A1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get active cell row in A1 cell every time I click on cell in Google sheet.

Thanks in advance!
Dane

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's not possible.  There is no "click" event in a Google Sheet.

Comment: Documentation for available triggers is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: Thank you all!
I didn't find solution yet! If I catch something I'll let you know.